# multiple file selection using inputFileUpload tag

Tags: java, jsf-2, tomahawk

**I am using JSF framework with apache's tomahwak library.**
how can i select multiple files using **inputFileUpload** tag in JSF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible.

Tomahawk's `<t:inputFileUpload>` renders a HTML4 `<input type="file">` element which at its own already doesn't support multiple file selection. You need to look for another JSF component which renders a HTML5 `<input type="file" multiple>` (which has currently however limited browser support) and/or uses undercovers a Flash Application or a Java Applet instead for the job.

As far as it comes to mind, [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf) is the only component library with such a component. [RichFaces](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload&skin=blueSky) has also a multi file uploader, but you can only select a single file at once.